Reading .xlsx file with Python Pandas changes some '<' to '<.1'
I was given a very messy .xlsx file. It contains a multiheader. A small selection of these double headers looks like this.



zoxamide

zoxamide





zOaAd [ug/l] [NVT] [AW]
<
zOaAd [ug/l] [NVT] [OW]
<



As can be seen, every second column contains a '<' symbol. When I read this into pandas using
df = pd.read_excel(file, header=[0,1]) 

Then, when I look at the headers in this file, I can see the following:
df.columns

MultiIndex([( 'zoxamide', 'zOaAd [ug/l] [NVT] [AW]'),
            ( 'zoxamide',                       '<'),
            ( 'zoxamide', 'zOaAd [ug/l] [NVT] [OW]'),
            ( 'zoxamide',                     '<.1'),
            ...

Note now that one of the '<' symbol has been converted to '<.1'.
I have no idea how why this happens.

Pandas automatically de-duplicates the column names adding .1/.2/… to make them unambiguous. This is fully expected. You can remove them with df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'\.\d+$', "", regex=True) if needed.

I didn't make the connection with this ONLY happening with columns. I was afraid this might happen in other sections of the data too. This solves it.
